# if the eigenvalues of a matrix all have positive real part, must the matrices diagonal entries all be positive?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If the eigenvalues of a matrix all have positive real part, must the matrices diagonal entries all be positive?

This is true of symmetric matrices, however I'd like to know if this result holds more generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A counterexample:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1&3\\
-2&3
\end{array}\right)
$$
The eigenvalues are $1\pm\sqrt{2}i$.